# Android: How I can I add a background image to a GridLayout?

Tags: android, view, hierarchy

I have a GridLayout full of buttons - similar to a calculate with spaces between the buttons. I wants to skin the background including the those areas between the buttons but not the buttons themselves.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a means of setting a background image on the GridLayout itself or do I need to create a View hierarchy?

I had started experimenting thinking that child Views can be added to parent Views but it would appear that you can only add Views to ViewGroup derived classes?

Without a background, I'm dynamically constructing my GridLayout and adding it to the activity's default layout using setContentView( gridLayout ).

How would I go about doing this please?

EDIT: What I would really like to understand is how to compose complex view hierachies. It also appears the simple approach of gridLayout.setBackground() requires API 16 and I'm using API 14 for my devices too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridView is derived from [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class. The View class has a method called  [void setBackgroundResource ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29), you can call it on your grid view object, pass an id of a drawable resource to it. This method was introduced since API level 1, so you don't have to worry about API compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks - I still have the problem with the child views not drawing properly because the GridLayout background is a nine-patch drawable but I'll ask that question elsewhere since its different from my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background image to a GridLayout easily like this:

A) `gridLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_image);`

B)
`Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background_image);
gridLayout.setBackground(drawable);`

However, please note, that I found when OTA upgraded from Android 6.0 to 7.1.1 (Galaxy J5 (2016)), that GridLayout doesn't support displaying a background drawable since API 24. (Neither of the above code seems to be working above API 23, not even on Android Emulator images)

However, TableLayout's background image is properly displayed even at API 24+.

(Therefore I had to rewrote all my relevant code from GridLayout to TableLayout, but these layouts quite similar, so it not much a problem.)